# How can I automatically populate a data frame with hourly values and fill the blank values with zeroes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data that I extract from an Elasticsearch system that shows employees' availability over the course of a date range, broken down into hourly slots.

Associates are never available for 24 hours per day, but I want to display the data across 24 hourly slots, with `0`s populating the cells where no data are present.

My thoughts are that I need to to create up a blank data frame, impute the results into it and then populate the rest with `0`s, but I would really like to know if there is a better way.

Note that the size of the initial data frame is not always the same size because different days return different hourly values (seven hour-long slots, three hour-long slots, 12 hour-long slots and so on).

Also note that where there aren't any hits/results from the query results, the hourly slots in between do not appear as there are no associated data (see between `18:00` and `21:00`).

At present, the whole data frame looks like this:

```
   hour                associate_count minutes_covered
   <dttm>                        <int>           <dbl>
1  2018-08-06 10:00:00               2              37
2  2018-08-06 11:00:00               2              60
3  2018-08-06 12:00:00               2              42
4  2018-08-06 13:00:00               1              56
5  2018-08-06 14:00:00               2              60
6  2018-08-06 15:00:00               2              60
7  2018-08-06 16:00:00               2              60
8  2018-08-06 17:00:00               1              52
9  2018-08-06 18:00:00               1               0 # NOTE THAT THERE IS A 3-HOUR GAP HERE UNTIL THE NEXT HIT
10 2018-08-06 21:00:00               1              10
```

The data behind the data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(hour = structure(c(1533546000, 1533549600, 1533553200, 
1533556800, 1533560400, 1533564000, 1533567600, 1533571200, 1533574800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/London"), 
    associate_count = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    minutes_covered = c(37, 60, 42, 56, 60, 60, 60, 52, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I get the data to look like this?

```
               hour associate_count minutes_covered
1  2018-08-06 00:00               0               0
2  2018-08-06 01:00               0               0
3  2018-08-06 02:00               0               0
4  2018-08-06 03:00               0               0
5  2018-08-06 04:00               0               0
6  2018-08-06 05:00               0               0
7  2018-08-06 06:00               0               0
8  2018-08-06 07:00               0               0
9  2018-08-06 08:00               0               0
10 2018-08-06 09:00               0               0
11 2018-08-06 10:00               2              37
12 2018-08-06 11:00               2              60
13 2018-08-06 12:00               2              42
14 2018-08-06 13:00               1              56
15 2018-08-06 14:00               2              60
16 2018-08-06 15:00               2              60
17 2018-08-06 16:00               2              60
18 2018-08-06 17:00               1              52
19 2018-08-06 18:00               1               0
20 2018-08-06 19:00               0               0
21 2018-08-06 20:00               0               0
22 2018-08-06 21:00               1              10
23 2018-08-06 22:00               0               0
24 2018-08-06 23:00               0               0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete` for this. It lets you additionally fill out other variables to expand the data frame with, if needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- structure(list(hour = structure(c(1533546000, 1533549600, 1533553200, 1533556800, 1533560400, 1533564000, 1533567600, 1533571200, 1533574800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/London"), associate_count = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), minutes_covered = c(37, 60, 42, 56, 60, 60, 60, 52, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

my_complete <- function(df, start_date, end_date){
  start_hour <- str_c(start_date, " 00:00:00") %>% ymd_hms
  end_hour <- str_c(end_date, " 00:00:00") %>% ymd_hms
  df %>%
    complete(
      hour = seq(from = start_hour, to = end_hour, by = "hour"),
      fill = list(associate_count = 0L, minutes_covered = 0)
    )
}
my_complete(df, "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07")
#> # A tibble: 25 x 3
#>    hour                associate_count minutes_covered
#>    <dttm>                        <int>           <dbl>
#>  1 2018-08-06 00:00:00               0               0
#>  2 2018-08-06 01:00:00               0               0
#>  3 2018-08-06 02:00:00               0               0
#>  4 2018-08-06 03:00:00               0               0
#>  5 2018-08-06 04:00:00               0               0
#>  6 2018-08-06 05:00:00               0               0
#>  7 2018-08-06 06:00:00               0               0
#>  8 2018-08-06 07:00:00               0               0
#>  9 2018-08-06 08:00:00               0               0
#> 10 2018-08-06 09:00:00               2              37
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Lubridate is part of the Tidyverse, so no need to load it separately. Upvote.

Comment: This is _almost_ perfect. This code is part of a function that I have where `start_date` and `end_date` arguments are passed (such as `"2018-08-06", "2018-08-10"` respectively) and I would like to use these values in your solution. Later on in the function, I `cbind()` several other data frames together (always of the same shape) but the problem that I am experiencing here is that I cannot pass `start_date` and `end_date` to `from` and `to` in your solution.  Can this be done. so that the resulting data frame is dynamically generated based on the arguments that are passed?

Comment: @DanY at least on my machine, with tidyverse 1.2.1, lubridate is not automatically loaded with `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy I edited to wrap this pipe in a function, illustrating how to force the date-string input to be date-time so we can use seq.POSIXt. (basically just add some zeroes and use a date-time parser)

Comment: My mistake - sorry.  `library(tidyverse)` only loads the _core_ tidyverse packages, and this does not include lubridate.

Comment: @CalumYou I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work (I think because I need to put in a function call within the main function). Perhaps I'm not implementing it correctly; I will keep trying, but in the interim is there a way to add the time values, as per my previous comment? If anything, the previous solution works better for me as this is part of a much larger function.

Comment: Don't put the function inside your function, put the body inside your function and use your existing `start_date` and `end_date` parameters. If it still isn't working you'll need to try doing more debugging. make sure you understand what `complete` does and what `seq` does and what types of object need to get passed to `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a sequence of hours for your day
allhours <- data.frame(hour=seq(from= as.POSIXct("2018-06-08 00:00"), 
                                to  = as.POSIXct("2018-06-08 23:00"), 
                                by  = "hours"))

# merge that sequence with your data (all=TRUE is important here)
res <- merge(df, allhours, by="hour", all=TRUE)

# convert NAs to Zeros
res[is.na(res$associate_count), "associate_count"] <- 0
res[is.na(res$minutes_covered), "minutes_covered"] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the expected output should be. But we may go somewhere starting around this:

```
new_df <- data.frame(hour=seq(ymd_hms('2018-08-06 00:00:00'),
                     ymd_hms('2018-08-06 23:00:00'), by = '1 hour'))
```

Now we can join with the old data frame

```
new_df %>% left_join(df)
Joining, by = "hour"
                  hour associate_count minutes_covered
1  2018-08-06 00:00:00              NA              NA
2  2018-08-06 01:00:00              NA              NA
3  2018-08-06 02:00:00              NA              NA
4  2018-08-06 03:00:00              NA              NA
5  2018-08-06 04:00:00              NA              NA
6  2018-08-06 05:00:00              NA              NA
7  2018-08-06 06:00:00              NA              NA
8  2018-08-06 07:00:00              NA              NA
9  2018-08-06 08:00:00              NA              NA
10 2018-08-06 09:00:00               2              37
11 2018-08-06 10:00:00               2              60
12 2018-08-06 11:00:00               2              42
13 2018-08-06 12:00:00               1              56
14 2018-08-06 13:00:00               2              60
15 2018-08-06 14:00:00               2              60
16 2018-08-06 15:00:00               2              60
17 2018-08-06 16:00:00               1              52
18 2018-08-06 17:00:00               1               0
19 2018-08-06 18:00:00              NA              NA
20 2018-08-06 19:00:00              NA              NA
21 2018-08-06 20:00:00              NA              NA
22 2018-08-06 21:00:00              NA              NA
23 2018-08-06 22:00:00              NA              NA
24 2018-08-06 23:00:00              NA              NA
```

If absolutely must get rid of the `NAs` and you need them to be zero you can add another pipe term like this `%>% mutate_at(c(2:3), funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))`